# Why is a custom resolver needed here (AutoMapper)?

Tags: automapper, automapping, automapper-2

Given the following entity model:

```
public class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Coordinates Center { get; set; }
}
public class Coordinates
{
    public double? Latitude { get; set; }
    public double? Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

... and the following view model:

```
public class LocationModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double? CenterLatitude { get; set; }
    public double? CenterLongitude { get; set; }
}
```

The LocationModel properties are named such that mapping from the entity to the model does not require a custom resolver.

However when mapping from a model to an entity, the following custom resolver is needed:

```
CreateMap<LocationModel, Location>()
    .ForMember(target => target.Center, opt => opt
        .ResolveUsing(source => new Coordinates 
            { 
                Latitude = source.CenterLatitude, 
                Longitude = source.CenterLongitude 
            }))
```

Why is this? Is there a simpler way to make AutoMapper to construct a new Coordinates value object based on the naming conventions in the viewmodel?

**Update**

To answer the first comment, there is nothing special about the entity to viewmodel mapping:

```
CreateMap<Location, LocationModel>();
```

Comment: Can you include the mapping from the entity to the model?

Comment: I have included the mapping from the entity to the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

Please see comment thread below. This answer is actually for the opposite mapping.

---

You're doing something else wrong. You are following the convention correctly, so the mapping should work without any need for a resolver.

I just tried this test, and it passed:

```
public class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Coordinates Center { get; set; }
}

public class Coordinates
{
    public double? Latitude { get; set; }
    public double? Longitude { get; set; }
}

public class LocationModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double? CenterLatitude { get; set; }
    public double? CenterLongitude { get; set; }
}

[Test]
public void LocationMapsToLocationModel()
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<Location, LocationModel>();

    var location = new Location
    {
        Id = 1,
        Center = new Coordinates { Latitude = 1.11, Longitude = 2.22 }
    };

    var locationModel = Mapper.Map<LocationModel>(location);

    Assert.AreEqual(2.22, locationModel.CenterLongitude);
}
```

Comment: Yes. Mapping from the entity to the viewmodel works just fine. It's going the other way that I'm finding need for the resolver: `Mapper.CreateMap<LocationModel, Location>()`.

Comment: @olivehour, oops sorry about that. In that case, yes, I think you do need a custom resolver. As far as I know, AutoMapper doesn't do "unflattening", just flattening. You might want to look into ValueInjecter (note the spelling).

Comment: Thanks, never heard of that lib before.